# When is a change in stool appearance to be expected after starting baby on wet and solid foods

Tags: infant, food, solids, stools

We recently started our six months old daughter on vegetable purees and solid food, which she likes fine. She will eat a few spoons full, up to about 12 per meal. I read, and was told, to expect a change in stool appearance, frequency and smell, but about three weeks in, only the frequency has changed. The stool looks about the same as before, sort of like cottage cheese, usually a bright yellow color.

We feed her both some pureed vegetables, oatmeal, but also BLW-style small pieces of solid food, such as cauliflower, potatoes, carrots or pasta. Practically every time she poops the food comes out as it went in, usually tinted in the foods color (pumpkin, beetroot, etc). I get that the solids are hard to digest properly in the beginning, but the wet foods?

Is she not digesting any of it? What is an average time until you should expect to see a change? I know the topic is not very exciting, but any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the solids are completely unchanged? Beets and some other veggies do change the color of poop, but do the solids you give her come out in tiny pieces or unchanged?

Comment: I would start her on rice cereal mixed into her formula or breast milk. Then start on stage 1 foods (pureed and only 1 thing). The poop consistency should change pretty quickly. My 5.5 month son's poop has consistency of peanut butter and is less frequent now. But every baby is different, you should work with your pediatrician.

Comment: We are concentrating on carrot puree right now, with solid food like some fruit and vegetable pieces, mostly for entertainment purposes. The stool is mostly unchanged, but has become slightly thicker and, of course, more orange. I will update further, when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody posted a definitive answer on this, I'd like to share *my own experience* at this point, two months after posing the question.

**Warning: this post includes images of actual baby stool!**

If I recall correctly, my daughter's stool began to change only about 3 weeks ago, so about 5 weeks after I posted the question. We have been feeding her pieces of most of what my wife and I eat, as finger food, but also fruit and/or vegetable purees with every lunch, oatmeal or grits for breakfast and supper. She is doing very well and is increasingly enjoying more solid pieces of food. The stool is now a 4 to 5 on the [Bristol stool scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_stool_scale), so more or less smooth. She usually goes a few minutes after breakfast and dinner, with only few exceptions.

For reference, over the past few weeks I have collected images (sadly not many old images), which I will post here.

**Watch out: baby poop images on mouseover!**

September 17

> [image: sept 17]

September 22

> [image: sept 22]

October 22

> [image: oct 22]

November 5

> [image: nov 5]

November 30

> [image: nov 30]

December 1

> [image: dec 1]

December 2

> [image: dec 2]

December 4

> [image: dec 4]

December 5

> [image: dec 5]
>  [image: dec 5]